# Delphi FireDac - Get auto-incremented value after overriding post Updates

Tags: delphi, firedac

I use FireDac with an Oracle 12c Database and Delphi Seattle.

I have a table Employee

```
EmployeeID - NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
HireDate - Date
```

On my form i have a FDQuery with the following statement:

```
select * from Employee
```

After FDQuery1.Insert and FDQuery1.Post i can get the generated EmployeeID with the following code:

```
  FDQuery1.Insert;
  ...
  FDQuery1.Post;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(FDQuery1.FieldByName('EMPLOYEEID').AsInteger));
```

This is working great.

**The problem:**

I now want to override the FDQuery Posting Updates like described here:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Overriding_Posting_Updates_%28FireDAC%29

So i override the posting updates:

```
procedure TForm3.FDQuery1UpdateRecord(ASender: TDataSet;
  ARequest: TFDUpdateRequest; var AAction: TFDErrorAction;
  AOptions: TFDUpdateRowOptions);
begin
  FDUpdateSQL1.ConnectionName := FDQuery1.ConnectionName;
  FDUpdateSQL1.DataSet := FDQuery1;
  FDUpdateSQL1.Apply(ARequest, AAction, AOptions);

  AAction := eaApplied;
end;
```

But now the EMPLOYEEID shows as -1 :(

```
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(FDQuery1.FieldByName('EMPLOYEEID').AsInteger));
```

It doesn't matter what statement i enter in FDUpdateSQL1.InsertSQL. I can even leave it blank. The result is always the same.

(This was also asked on https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=778896&#778896)

Answer (score 0):

[By  Dmitry Arefiev     from the Embarcadero Discussion Forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=176038&tstart=0):

Try to use INSERT ... RETURNING EmployeeID INTO :NEW_EmployeeID in
your FDUpdateSQL1.InsertSQL. You will need also setup :NEW_EmployeeID
parameter like that:

```
with FDUpdateSQL1.Commands[arInsert].ParamByName('NEW_EmployeeID') do begin
  ParamType := ptOutput;
  DataType := ftInteger;
end;
```

Comment: Glad you got his attention.

Comment: Thanks again for proving the link to their forums. So much useful information. Btw Dimitry seems like an awesome guy.

Comment: Presumably that's why EMBA brought his product in-house ;=)